# mysql select latest record only for record

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with the following structure:

```
custodian | counta | countc | countc | total | date
-------------------------------------------------------
ed        | 1      | 2      | 3      | 6     | 1/1/2016
ed        | 2      | 3      | 5      | 10    | 1/2/2016
ed        | 2      | 3      | 6      | 11    | 1/3/2016
ed        | 1      | 3      | 5      | 9     | 1/4/2016
fred      | 1      | 2      | 3      | 6     | 1/1/2016
fred      | 2      | 3      | 5      | 10    | 1/2/2016
fred      | 2      | 3      | 6      | 11    | 1/3/2016
fred      | 1      | 3      | 5      | 9     | 1/4/2016
```

How do I return the latest record for a custodian? I've been playing around with this condition `where date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 59 MINUTE)` since the table is updated hourly, but if I update the script twice in an hour, I would return more than one result per custodian.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTableName
WHERE custodian = 123
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Just got in before me! On a related note, I'm suprised that `LIMIT` isn't syntax highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

The most recent date will be the first record when ordered decendingly, and limiting the select to 1 means you get only the latest record.